# Testing Django querysets: self.assertListEqual vs self.assertQuerysetEqual

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing

Testing in Django I've found two different ways to test functions that involve querysets. The first one is:

```
test_instance = FooFactory()
self.assertListEqual(list(Foo.objects.all()), [test_instance])
```

And the second one is:

```
test_instance = FooFactory()
self.assertQuerysetEqual(Foo.objects.all(), map(repr, [test_instance]))
```

Which of these two are better? I read from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual) that this is what `assertQuerysetEqual` does:

> Asserts that a queryset qs returns a particular list of values values.
>
> The comparison of the contents of qs and values is performed using the function transform; by default, this means that the repr() of each value is compared. Any other callable can be used if repr() doesn’t provide a unique or helpful comparison.
>
> By default, the comparison is also ordering dependent. If qs doesn’t provide an implicit ordering, you can set the ordered parameter to False, which turns the comparison into a collections.Counter comparison. If the order is undefined (if the given qs isn’t ordered and the comparison is against more than one ordered values), a ValueError is raised.

I see two important things here: one is that the `repr()` of each value is compared, and the other is that `assertQuerysetEqual` allows you to make ordering optional.

For the first point, I think it's better to compare the models themselves instead of their `repr` values since then you know that they are exactly the same (although one could also make the argument that `repr` values should be distinct).

For the second, I can see how unordered comparisons could be useful. Then again, if you're specifically testing something where ordering isn't important/is easily simulated, I don't see the advantage there.

The only argument I can think of for `assertQuerysetEqual` (with those assumptions above) is that it's more readable/direct about its purpose.

Is there any practical difference between `self.assertListEqual(list(<queryset>), [<expected_models_in_correct_order>])` and `self.assertQuerysetEqual(<queryset>, map(repr, [<expected_models_in_correct_order>])` that I failed to account for?

Answer (score 0):

The only practical difference is in how python does object and string comparison.

**self.assertListEqual**: compares list of model instances delegating to an `__eq__` method which provides a rule for how comparison is done. [See how Django does comparison for model instances](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/base.py#L598).

**self.assertQuerysetEqual**: compares list of strings using the `ord` value of each character in each string.

Depending on how `__eq__` and `__repr__` is implemented for the object, one may provide slight performance gains over the other.